# Create more than two StatusBar parts

Tags: c, winapi

I am unable to create more than two StatusBar parts:

```
HWND hStatusBar = CreateWindowEx(0, STATUSCLASSNAME, "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

int arr[3] = {100, 100, -1};
SendMessage(hStatusBar, SB_SETPARTS, 3, (LPARAM)arr);
```

This code is supposed to create three parts, but it is creating only two! What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`SB_SETPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation:

> Each element specifies the position, in client coordinates, of the
>   right edge of the corresponding part

Your first two parts are at the same position (i.e. they are exactly overlapping), and so you can only see one of them. You need to increment the right edge for each subsequent part:

```
int arr[3] = { 100, 200, -1 };
```